# RecyclerView image flicker when using notifyItemChanged and Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've seen a few questions that are somewhat similar but have significant differences.

**Expected:**

I have a vertical `RecyclerView` of cells with an image and some buttons below it. The image is dynamically sized and loaded using `Glide`. When the user clicks a button it updates the dataset and performs `notifyItemChanged` on the item in which the button was clicked. This should then smoothly reload the cell with the same image and any necessary state changes.

**Actual**

When the user clicks the button the cell and buttons are reloaded as desired but the image flickers significantly as it snaps back into size from 0 height to full height.

**What I have so far**

From my understanding this is happening because `onBindViewHolder` is called on that cell which also reloads the image via glide (thus causing the flicker). I added an if check to try and prevent image reload if the same image or holder is being acted upon. Example:

```
if (holder.tag == null || !holder.tag.equals(item.getId())) {
     // Load image via Glide
}
```

However this doesn't not trigger properly. It seems that when `onBindViewHolder` is called, the cell that is being bound for the same position isn't the same cell but some other inactive cell (the cell itself isn't being reused but instead a different inactive one is being brought in to replace it).

**Questions**

- Is replacing the visible cell with an inactive one that is then reconfigured the expected re-use behaviour for `notifyItemChanged`.
- If so is there anything else I can do to reconfigured only some pieces of the active cell upon user interaction. Ideally I don't want to fully throw out the cell and redraw or I'll end up with the same image flickering.

**Temporary workaround**

I reload the RecyclerView items from the db without notifying and then manually changing the button states using the reference to the holder from inside the onClick. I would much rather do this "properly" by simply being able to rebind the whole view

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried disabling the default animation of recycler view ??Not sure but it might help .

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it didn't seem to help for me. Just changed the snap in of the image on refresh to be 0-full size in one step rather than a smooth animation from 0-fullsize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced this issue and found the solution by using Picasso. Picasso has a nice method call for this [`.noPlaceholder()`](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#noPlaceholder--)

What it does is tell Picasso to not strip the old image from the view before placing the new image. Which is what causes the blink on the ImageView. It seems Picasso is reloading the image which is not good but at least your user will not see the blink

```
              Picasso.get()
                .load(itemModel().getImageUrl())
                .error(R.drawable.place_holder_image)
                .noPlaceholder()
                .into(holder.postImage);
```

EDIT: In the above solution you will notice issues when the view is recycled. Mainly Picasso will have old images showing before showing the new one (since the view was recycled). Here is another solution. If you know the image view doesn't need to be reloaded than don't let Picasso attempt to reload.

```
 if (holder.postImage.getTag() == null || !itemModel().getImageUrl().equals((String)holder.postImage.getTag())) {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(model.getImageUrl())
                    .error(R.drawable.place_holder_image)
                    //.noPlaceholder() --Don't use this.
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder_image)
                    .into(holder.postImage);
            holder.postImage.setTag(model.getImageUrl());
        }
```

Comment: Had a look at their documentation and it looks like by design it functions in the way you described - stripping the image first before the new one is loaded in which is causing the flicker. This answers the question thank you!

Comment: I have found an issue with this solution. It sees my recycler will now sometimes show the wrong image momentarily. So for example I scroll through and get to the bottom of my feed. I quickly scroll up, some image views will have old views images before reloading the new one. Based on how the API works I understand this would happen. Just FYI.